# Getting url data by curl method giving unexpected results in symbols

Tags: php, curl

I am facing some times Problem in getting url data by curl method specially website data is is in other language like arabic etc
My curl function is

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

    //checking mime types
    if(strstr($info,'text/html')) {
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And how i am getting data

```
$html =  file_get_contents_curl($checkurl);
    $grid ='';
    if($html)
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTML($html);
        $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
        @$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
        @$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
        for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
        {
            $meta = $metas->item($i);
            if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
                $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        }
```

I am getting all data correctly from some arabic websites like 
http://www.emaratalyoum.com/multimedia/videos/2012-04-08-1.474873
and when i give this youtube url 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eyxljw31TtU&feature=g-logo&context=G2c4f841FOAAAAAAAFAA
it shows symbols..
what setting i have to do to show exactly the same title description.

Comment: maybe this help ? `$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');`

Comment: Hi, I had spent a lot of times on similar problems, and there isn't a general work-around.

Youtube URL is giving content in UTF8, therefore ajreal's suggestion can be useful.

Try also the following approaches:
1. to convert using iconv: `$description = @iconv( "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $description );`
2. to convert using `mb_convert_encoding` (this requires Multibyte support for PHP)

Comment: user utf8_decode($description).. this will solve the problem...

Answer (score 6):

#### Introduction

Getting Arabic can be very tricky but they are some basic steps you need to ensure

- Your document must output `UTF-8`
- Your DOMDocument must read in UTF-8 fromat

#### Problem

When getting Youtube information its already given the information in "UTF-8" format and the retrieval process adds addition `UTF-8` encoding .... not sure why this occurs but a simple `utf8_decode` would fix the issue

#### Example

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
echo displayMeta("http://www.emaratalyoum.com/multimedia/videos/2012-04-08-1.474873");
echo displayMeta("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eyxljw31TtU&feature=g-logo&context=G2c4f841FOAAAAAAAFAA");
```

#### Output

***emaratalyoum.com***

```
التقطت عدسات الكاميرا حارس مرمى ريال مدريد إيكر كاسياس في موقف محرج قبل لحظات من بداية مباراة النادي الملكي مع أبويل القبرصي في ذهاب دور الثمانية لدوري أبطال
```

***youtube.com***

```
أوروبا.ففي النفق المؤدي إلى الملعب، قام كاسياس بوضع إصبعه في أنفه، وبعدها قام بمسح يده في وجه أحدبنات سعوديات: أريد "شايب يدللني ولا شاب يعللني"
```

#### Function Used

***displayMeta***

```
function displayMeta($checkurl) {
    $html = file_get_contents_curl($checkurl);
    $grid = '';
    if ($html) {
        $doc = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
        @$doc->loadHTML($html);
        $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
        $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
        for($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i ++) {
            $meta = $metas->item($i);
            if ($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description') {
                $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
                if (stripos(parse_url($checkurl, PHP_URL_HOST), "youtube") !== false)
                    return utf8_decode($description);
                else {
                    return $description;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***file_get_contents_curl***

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

    // checking mime types
    if (strstr($info, 'text/html')) {
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work... utf8_decode()  your attribute..

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

//checking mime types
if(strstr($info,'text/html')) {
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
} else {
    return false;
}
}

$html =  file_get_contents_curl($checkurl);
$grid ='';
if($html)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
    @$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    @$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
    for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
    {
        $meta = $metas->item($i);
        if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
            $description = utf8_decode($meta->getAttribute('content'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is that you're discarding the found `Content-Type` header that cURL returned in your `file_get_contents_curl()` function; `DOMDocument` needs that information to understand the character set that was used on the page.

A somewhat ugly hack, but most generic, is to prefix the returned page with a `<meta>` tag containing the returned character set from the response headers:

```
if (strstr($info, 'text/html')) {
    curl_close($ch);
    return '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="' . $info . '" />' . $data;
}
```

DOMDocument will accept the misplaced meta tag and do the respective conversions automatically.